# Approaches to execute PostgreSQL's concat() instead of || in JOOQ?

Tags: postgresql, jooq

The `||`-operator and the `concat(...)`-function in PostgreSQL behave differently.

```
select 'ABC'||NULL||'def';
-- Result: NULL

select concat('ABC', NULL, 'def');
-- Result: 'ABCdef'
```

`concat(...)` ignores NULL values, but a NULL whithin a `||` expression makes the whole result become NULL.

In JOOQ, the `DSL.concat()` in the PostgreSQL dialect renders expressions using the `||`-operator:

```
Java: dsl.select(
        DSL.concat(
          DSL.inline("ABC"), 
          DSL.inline(null, SQLDataType.VARCHAR), 
          DSL.inline("def"))
      ).execute();
SQL: select ('ABC' || null || 'def')
Result: NULL
```

I am looking for (elegant?) ways to invoke the `concat(...)`-function instead of the `||`-operator via JOOQ in PostgreSQL:

```
Java: dsl.select(???).execute();
SQL: select concat('ABC', null, 'def')
Result: 'ABCdef'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found two ways to achieve the posed objective.

Approach #1:

```
dsl.select(
  field(
    "concat({0})",
    SQLDataType.VARCHAR,
    list(
      inline("ABC"), 
      inline(null, SQLDataType.VARCHAR), 
      inline("def")
    )
  )
).execute();
```

This has the intended behavior, but necessitates the in my eyes ugly `"concat({0})"`. A more elegant approach from my point of view is:

Approach #2:

```
dsl.select(
  function(
    "concat", 
    SQLDataType.VARCHAR, 
    inline("ABC"), 
    inline(null, SQLDataType.VARCHAR), 
    inline("def")
  )
).execute();
```

This solution does not involve inline SQL with placeholders as approach #1. Why JOOQ generates `||` instead of `concat(...)` in the first place is still to be expounded, though.